# FactoryGirl outside of rails getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, factory

I am writing FactoryGirl outside of rails application. I have created a factory in support/factories.rb

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { "a123456Q" }
    address { Faker::Address.street_name }
    mobile {"1234567890"}
    country {"india"}
    login {Faker::Name.first_name}
  end
end
```

Made connection in env.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql2',
  :host => 'localhost',
  :database => 'consultancy',
  :username => "root",
  :password => "")

puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from users")
```

Here puts return `<Mysql2::Result:0xa932d80>`

And when run command `FactoryGirl.factories` It return

```
#<FactoryGirl::Registry:0xa39d118 @name="Factory", @items={:user=>#<FactoryGirl::Factory:0xb2e82d0 @name=:user, @parent=nil, @aliases=[], @class_name=nil, @definition=#<FactoryGirl::Definition:0xb000f68 @declarations=#<FactoryGirl::DeclarationList:0xb000f90 @declarations=[#<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0xa66b098 @name=:first_name, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0xa66b070@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:5>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0x9ac5f7c @name=:last_name, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0x9ac5cd4@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:6>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0x9ef23fc @name=:email, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0x9ef2168@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:7>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0xa737e2c @name=:password, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0xa737760@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:8>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0xa29a630 @name=:address, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0x9f761e8@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:9>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0xa145b04 @name=:mobile, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0xa754d74@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:10>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0xa5d4918 @name=:country, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0xa5d4878@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:11>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0xa5d4b5c @name=:login, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0xa5d4ae4@/home/vijay_demo_project/bank_cucumber/features/support/factories.rb:12>>], @name=:user, @overridable=false>, @callbacks=[], @defined_traits=[], @to_create=nil, @base_traits=[], @additional_traits=[], @constructor=nil, @attributes=nil, @compiled=false>, @compiled=false>}>
```

But when I create build getting error.

```
 FactoryGirl.build(:user)
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant User
```

Rails have a model User and present tables users in database.

Please help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point where you call `FactoryGirl.build(:user)`, the `User` model (defined in `user.rb`) has not been loaded into memory yet. Try using `require 'app/models/user.rb'` just before you invoke `FactoryGirl.build(:user)`.

Comment: I have writing FactoryGirl for Cucumber script but when I require 'app/models/user.rb' getting error *** LoadError Exception: cannot load such file -- app/models/user.rb

Comment: Yes I am using ActiveRecord and required it

Comment: Just to be sure I understand you - do you mean you were able to successfully require `app/models/user.rb`, and you are still getting the same error?

Comment: I am not able to require app/models/user.rb and getting same error

Comment: If you are using ActivRecord and have required it, then in the factories.rb I would expect see something like this class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end

Comment: Now I am able to require by complete path require '/home/demo_projects/openhome/app/models/user.rb'